# Partial class specialization using type traits

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, sfinae, template-specialization

I am pretty new to C++, and I have run into an issue I can't seem to fix or find someone else who had the same issue.

I have a class `Polynomial` as defined:

```
template<class C>
class Polynomial {
    std::vector<C> coefficients;
    ...
public:
    ...
    const double integral(double, double);
    ...
};
```

I need to make sure, that the `integral()` method can not be called if `C` is an integral type. Obviously that means using type traits, HOWEVER I have tried using `template<typename = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<C>::value, C>::type>` on the method itself, and although it would compile, I could now not make an object with integral types as the template argument.

I then thought, that it should be possible to create partial specializations of the `Polynomial` class, that is to have a specialization of the class with floating points, one with integral and one with complex numbers. Something along the lines of

```
template<typename C>
class Polynomial<typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<C>::value, C>::type> : Polynomial<C> {
public:
    const double integral(double, double);
};
```

However, not matter how I do this, it never seems to work.

I guess the question I have is: How is it possible to specify a partial specialization of classes using type traits as the specialization?

I hope you can help.

Comment: Back up. What do you mean by "can not be called"? Is it enough if, when you call it, you get a compile error with a reasonable message? Or do you need more than that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a separate base class for the common stuff, then you can make the template specializations for `Polynomial` like this:

```
template<class C>
class PolynomialBase {
    std::vector<C> coefficients;
};    

template <typename T, typename Enable = void>
class Polynomial;

template<typename C>
class Polynomial<C, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<C>::value>::type> : PolynomialBase<C> {
public:
     const double integral(double, double);
};    

template<typename C>
class Polynomial<C, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<C>::value>::type> : PolynomialBase<C> {};
```

Answer (score 4):

It's too late to play?

You, obviously, can solve the problem through specialization and the krisz's answer show a possible way.

But you can solve it simply enabling/disabling `integral()` through SFINAE.

You can't check the `C` type because SFINAE works over templates specific for the method, not of the class, so you have to make `integral()` a template method.

By example

```
  template <typename D = C>
  std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<D>::value, double>
     integral (double, double)
   { return 1.0; }
```

This way you can check the `D` type that is defaulted with the `C` type.

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename C>
class Polynomial
 {
   private:
      std::vector<C> coefficients;

   public:
      template <typename D = C>
      std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<D>::value, double>
         integral (double, double)
       { return 1.0; }
 };

int main()
 {
   Polynomial<float>  pf;
   Polynomial<int>    pi;

   pf.integral(0.0, 0.0);  // compile

   // pi.integral(0.0, 0.0);  // compilation error
 }
```

The problem of this solution is that can be "hijacked" if you explicit the `D` type

```
   Polynomial<int>    pi;

   // pi.integral(0.0, 0.0);  // compilation error

   pi.integral<double>(0.0, 0.0); // hijacked: compile
```

To avoid the hijacking problem you can modify the SFINAE test for `integral()` imposing also that `C` and `D` are the same type

So if you write it as follows

```
  template <typename D = C>
  std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<D>::value
                && std::is_same<C, D>::value, double>
     integral (double, double)
   { return 1.0; }
```

the `integral()` can't be hijacked anymore

```
    Polynomial<int>    pi;

   // pi.integral(0.0, 0.0);  // compilation error

   // pi.integral<double>(0.0, 0.0); // compilation error
```